# What do we mean by the terms "logical" and "physical" from the aspect of computer science?

Tags: java, computer-science

I have come across with the term 'logical' and 'physical' in many subjects. For example, in SQL, there is logical and physical order of data; in Java, there is logical entity(class) and physical entity(object). In Operating System there is logical address and physical address. Still I don't know what are these terms "logical" and "physical' actually mean from a Computer Science perspective. Please explain.

Comment: Those are three completely different things (the java one, by the way, I've never heard of), so you're basically asking three different questions.

Comment: In OS **Physical Address** as the name suggests is the actual address of data inside the main memory. It is also called *Real address* or *Binary address*.

**Logical address** is a virtual address. It is generated by the CPU during program execution. It does not exist physically, and therefore, it is also known as a *Virtual Address*.
Same logic can be applied others.
A **class** is a logical entity, while an **object** is a physical entity. A class does not allocate memory space; on the other hand, an object allocates memory space.

Comment: A linked list can be example where the logical order is different from the physical order. Suppose the code for a linked list creates a `new` node, and then links as the tail. In memory, its location can be before or after the previous tail -- it's physical location. But, at this point, it's logical location is last.

Comment: The old IBM 370 had a record-oriented file management subsystem. Physical I/O handled transferring data, in either direction, between a buffer and the I/O device. Logical I/O handled transferring data, in either direction, between the buffer and the running program. Logical I/O handled record block management.

Answer (score 0):

In computer science, the terms "logical" and "physical" are often used to distinguish between different levels of abstraction or organization.

A "logical" organization refers to the way in which data or information is organized, represented, or thought about in the context of a particular problem or system. For example, in SQL, the logical order of data refers to the way in which the data is organized and accessed in terms of the database schema, such as by table and column. In Java, a class is a logical entity, representing a blueprint for an object, which is a physical entity that exists in memory.

A "physical" organization, on the other hand, refers to the actual physical layout or organization of the data or information on a computer. For example, in SQL, the physical order of data refers to the way in which the data is stored on disk, such as by file and block. In Operating System, the physical address refers to the actual memory address where the data is stored in the computer's memory.

In summary, Logical organization is the way in which data is thought about in the context of a problem or system, while Physical organization is the actual layout of data on a computer.